# Conditional Probability (Exam Pass/Fail)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

A student needs to take and pass three exams to pass a course. If she fails an exam she cannot
take the subsequent one(s) and fails the course. The probabilities of passing the exams are 0.9,
0.75 and 0.6 consecutively. Given that the student did not pass the course, what is the probability
that she failed the th exam,  = 1,2,3?

I tried to solve it with conditioning on failing for all i values. But seems like I am missing something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Fail first exam $p_1=0.1$, fail second exam $p_2=0.9\times 0.25=0.225$, fail third exam $p_3=0.9\times 0.75 \times 0.4=0.27$. Total $=0.595$  As you must see, failure on a later exam results only if previous exams passed.